# UIScrollView not scrolling properly.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a uiscrollview dragged onto the storyboard that is 320x570.

In my viewDidLoad, I have added in

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;   
self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size;
```

Now when I run the app on the iPhone 5 simulator, my view scrolls but not to the very bottom. When I run the app on the iPhone 4 (smaller screen), it does not scroll at all. What determines how far the scroll should go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.scrollView.contentSize` must be more than  `self.view.frame.size` to scroll.

Small example for you:

(X is extra place that must be scrollable to see in small screens.)

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + x)];
```

In you're case you set height of content same as you're main view so no scroll will be applied.

Comment: It does scroll in the iPhone 5, but it doesn't scroll to the desired y value. How can I set this ?

Comment: i do small example for you with setting of content size of scroll view and adjusting x place for content that is not fill in view.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk what is the `x` value on your code above?

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto (X is extra place that must be scrollable to see in small screens.)